# file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/XXX) is not within the allowed path(s): (/XXX) Ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, open-basedir

The problem is that type of error when I put my Laravel application on a server and Install a PDF plugin...

```
file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/XXXX) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/XXX)
```

So the problem here is that, there are too many wrong solutions on a internet, that said that we need to change `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` (a file that doesn't exist LOL)

Or some another solutions that I found are placing something like that on apache configuration file:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/home/admin/web/XXX">
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/admin/web/XXXX"
</DirectoryMatch>
```

But it still doesn't work...

Obviously I tried to change `open_basedir` on php.ini file... and NOTHING!!

So what is the right answer? (for me :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THE ANSWER**

I found an answer accidentally... And only because I have spended more than 10 hours to solve that, I'm writing that solution...

The variable that we need to change on `php.ini` **IS NOT** `open_basedir`

BUT: sys_temp_dir = "/home/admin/XXX"

and we also can leave `open_basedir` as comment...

SURPRISE!!! :D

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue? I am facing same issue